# chatting system between users

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have been trying to create a chatting system using php+ ajax + mysql.

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>
<html>  
  <head>  
       <title>Live Table Data Edit</title>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  </head>  
  <body>  
       <div class="container">  
            <br />  
            <br />  
            <br />  
            <div class="table-responsive">  
                 <h3 align="center">You Are : <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; 
                ?></h3><br />  
                 <div id="live_data"></div>                 
            </div>  
            <div id="messages"></div> 
            <div class="area" style="display:none">
            <textarea id="text" name="text"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" id="sub" name="sub" value="Send" />
            </div>
       </div>  

  </body>  
  </html>  

   <script>  
$(document).ready(function() {
  function fetch_data() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "select.php",
      method: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#live_data').html(data);
      }
    });
  }
  fetch_data();

  $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id1");

    function fetch_chat() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "fetch_chat.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          id: id
        },
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
          $('#messages').html(data);
          $("div.area").show();
        }

      });
    }

    fetch_chat();
    $("#sub").click(function() {
      var text = $("#text").val();
      $.post('insert_chat.php', {
        id: id,
        msg: text
      }, function(data) {
        $("#messages").append(data);
        $("#text").val('');

      });
      alert(text);
    });
  });
});
```

but the trouble is that when I try to insert a new message in mysql the messages is send to all the users in which i have clicked.

the fetch_chat.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test');
$id= $_POST['id'];
$sql="select * from users where id='$id'";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
$user_to= $row['name'];
$sql1="select * from chats where user_from='$_SESSION[name]' AND 
user_to='$user_to' OR user_to='$_SESSION[name]' AND user_from='$user_to' 
order  by id";
$res1=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res1)>0){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res1)){
?>
        <b> <?php echo $row['user_from']; ?>:</b> 
        <?php echo $row['msg']; ?><br /><br />
        <?php
    }
}
else
    echo "No msgs <br />";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

and insert_chat.php is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test');
$id= $_POST['id'];
$msg=$_POST['msg'];
$sql="select * from users where id='$id'";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
$user_to= $row['name'];

$sql1="insert into chats(user_from,user_to,msg) 
values('$_SESSION[name]','$user_to','$msg')";
$res1=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
if($res1){
?>
    <b> <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>:</b> 
    <?php echo $msg; ?><br /><br />
<?php   
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know where I am going wrong. Please help me with this.

For example, the list of users is:

(1) user a

(2) user b

(3) user c

So at first I clicked `a` then I changed my mind to select `b` and send the text. But there arises the problem: the data gets inserted for both a and b like I am texting both of them at the same time.

Comment: You mean when you get that message it shows in all chats  ? So have you checked how it is inserted in your database  ?

Comment: Not solving your problem, but a security note: You code is wide open to mysql injections! https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: My guess is the issue lives here: `"select * from chats where user_from='$_SESSION[name]' AND 
user_to='$user_to' OR user_to='$_SESSION[name]' AND user_from='$user_to' 
order  by id"` because you have an `OR` statement I assume should be parenthesized

Comment: thanx for ur valuable comments but pl go through my edits once

Comment: I think kchason's suggestion is in the right area. Check the results of that query. I don't think so much the message is "sent" to all users (in the sense of writing the message into the table repeatedly with different user_to IDs) but that you aren't retrieving the data you think you are when you fetch the chat

Comment: @adyson but the message is sent to both users a and b if i click b after clicking a

Comment: Is it, though? Are there two rows in the database for that message?

Comment: Also I note that you're using the user's "name" in the chats table to represent the user the message was sent to. Why do that, when you have an "id" field for the user? The user could legitimately change their display name, in which case you lose the link from message to user. Far safer to use id, which should be unique and un-changing, and also you should have a foreign key relationship between the tables to enforce integrity.

Comment: @adyson i think i m getting u a bit. it will be more helpful if u provide me with some codes only for inserting into the database coz there's i m messing up the whole thing

Comment: Oh I think I see the problem now that I formatted your code to be readable. You keep on adding more and more "click" event handlers to "sub", every time you click on "first_name". So then each time you click sub again, it runs _all_ the previous event handlers again and again. So you get the current message, but sent to all users you previously clicked on since you loaded the page. `$("#sub").click(function() {` needs to be `$("#sub").off("click").on("click", function() {` so that it removes previous handlers before you define the new version with new data.

Comment: @adyson wow thanks a lot........

Comment: I guess that worked? I have added as answer, if you would be kind enough to accept it - thanks :-)

Comment: @adyson just one more thing....... 
if user a is sending a text to b only the a's side message section is updating in real time..... what should i do to make the message visible to both the side ..... does it have something to do with setinterval();

Comment: @adyson thanks for that answer but help  me with setinterval() by providing a code. I have tried it but the screen starting blinking frequently.

Comment: @adyson  I have tried it and it worked only for the first user I chat with but the screen starting blinking frequently when I click on other users' name. my function code is like this: 

function myTimeoutFunction()
 {
  fetch_chat();
 }
 myTimeoutFunction();
        setInterval(myTimeoutFunction, 1000);

Comment: Can you ask a new question about it please? Then we can see the latest full code properly and diagnose it. Link to it from here if you want me to look at it.

Comment: @adyson here's the link of my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095716/refreshing-chat-body-for-each-of-the-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep on adding more and more "click" event handlers to "sub", every time you click on "first_name". So then each time you click sub again, it runs all the previous event handlers again and again. So you get the current message, but sent to all users you previously clicked on since you loaded the page.

```
$("#sub").click(function() {
```

needs to be

```
$("#sub").off("click").on("click", function() {
```

so that it removes previous handlers before you define the new version with new data.