# refreshing chat body for each of the users

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have been trying to create a chatting system using php+ ajax + mysql.

```
 <?php
   session_start();
 ?>
 <html>  
     <head>  
         <title>Live Table Data Edit</title>  
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
         <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
     </head>  
     <body>  
         <div class="container">  
            <br />  
            <br />  
            <br />  
            <div class="table-responsive">  
                 <h3 align="center">You Are : <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; 
                ?></h3><br />  
                 <div id="live_data"></div>                 
            </div>  
            <div id="messages"></div> 
            <div class="area" style="display:none">
            <textarea id="text" name="text"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" id="sub" name="sub" value="Send" />
            </div>
       </div>  
  </body>  
</html>  

<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {
  function fetch_data() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "select.php",
      method: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#live_data').html(data);
      }
    });
  }
  fetch_data();

  $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id1");

    function fetch_chat() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "fetch_chat.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          id: id
        },
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
          $('#messages').html(data);
          $("div.area").show();
        }

      });
    }

    function myTimeoutFunction() {
      fetch_chat();
    }

    myTimeoutFunction();
    setInterval(myTimeoutFunction, 1000);

    fetch_chat();
    $("#sub").click(function() {
      var text = $("#text").val();
      $.post('insert_chat.php', {
        id: id,
        msg: text
      }, function(data) {
        $("#messages").append(data);
        $("#text").val('');

      });
      alert(text);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

but the problem with this code is that it worked only for the first user I chat with but the screen starting blinking frequently when I click on other users' name. for example: user 'a' is logged in and click on user 'b' and starts the chat. everything works fine till now, but when user 'a' thinks to chat with a another user 'c' the whole chat part start blinking with all chats stored in database. plz tell me where I m goin wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs a complete rethink really, to be rid of all the potential bugs.

The problem you describe above is because you're creating a new timed interval every time someone clicks on a name, so gradually this builds up and you are requesting every few milliseconds instead of every second. This is unsustainable. There's no need really to be declaring intervals, functions etc etc within the "click" handler of the name. I think you're doing this because of the dependency on the user ID which results from selecting a name. However you can overcome that by assigning the value to a global variable.

Doing this means you can move all the functions outside the click handler, removing any danger of re-creating the same intervals / events multiple times. I've also changed it so it doesn't use an interval. Instead, fetch_chat calls itself again 2 seconds after the previous response is received. That way, if a fetch takes longer than normal, you don't have multiple competing fetch operations running in parallel and causing potential confusion. I also increased the time interval to something which is still reasonable, but won't overload the server.

Here's a complete rework of your code:

```
<script>
var currentID = null;
var chatTimer = null;

function fetch_data() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "select.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#live_data').html(data);
      fetch_chat();
    }
  });
}

function fetch_chat() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "fetch_chat.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      id: currentID
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#messages').html(data);
      $("div.area").show();
      chatTimer = setTimeout(fetch_chat, 2000); //request the chat again in 2 seconds time
    }

  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function() {
    currentID = $(this).data("id1");
    //immediately fetch chat for the new ID, and clear any waiting fetch timer that might be pending
    clearTimeout(chatTimer);
    fetch_chat(); 
  });

  $("#sub").click(function() {
    var text = $("#text").val();

    $.post('insert_chat.php', {
      id: currentID,
      msg: text
    }, function(data) {
      $("#messages").append(data);
      $("#text").val('');
    });
    alert(text);
  });

  fetch_data(); //this will also trigger the first fetch_chat once it completes
});
</script>
```

P.S. If you want anything faster than 2 seconds refresh, then really you probably need to consider re-architecting the solution using websockets to get full 2-way communication, so the server can "push" chat items to the client instead of the client having to poll the server.

Comment: thanx for all ur help. It really work for me.
and u were suggesting websockets,so can u share up a link to learn to use websockets in php . thanx once again.

Comment: No problem I haven't used websockets myself, tbh, I just know the theory, so I'm probably not the best person to ask for a specific resource. But I do know just from googling the topic that open-source projects exist which claim you can leverage them to get a working PHP websockets solution more easily than doing it yourself from scratch.

Comment: need some more assistance :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47112045/cant-scroll-up-the-div-contents

Answer (score 0):

You are using setInterval, this is wrong, this will start a loop every time you click on a chat, you should have a single loop running over all your chats. Also consider using setTimeout instead of setInterval to ensure you get the response first.

Comment: can u provide me the code.It will be very helpful for me.